# Express.js Form Submit: Updating list items on post

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

I have a webpage with a form to enter timecard entries  and a list of previous timecard entries.  Whenever a user submits the form I want their entry to immediately show up in the list.  The only way I can think to do this is to repeat the SELECT query twice, once on page load and once again after the post query.  However I don't really want to repeat the same query twice.  Is there a better way to structure my middleware so I don't have to repeat my code?

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  sql.connect(config).then(function() {
    new sql.Request().query(`
      SELECT company_id, company_name, project, category, start_time, end_time, duration, notes, date
      FROM time_card
      ORDER BY date DESC
    `).then(function(timecard) {
      res.locals.timecard = timecard;
      console.log(res.locals.timecard);
      next();
    }).catch(function(err) { next(err); });
  }).catch(function(err) { next(err); });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {});
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
  req.checkBody(schema);
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('index', { errors: errors, body: req.body });
  }else{
    var timeStamp = req.body.date + ' ' + req.body.time;
    var start = moment( timeStamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a' ).toString();
    var end = moment( timeStamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a' ).add(req.body.duration, 'milliseconds').toString();
    var inputs = req.body.project.split('-');
    var notes = req.body.notes ? req.body.notes : undefined;
    sql.connect(config).then(function() {
      new sql.Request()
      .input('company_name',  sql.NVarChar(50),       inputs[0].trim())
      .input('project',       sql.NVarChar(50),       inputs[1].trim())
      .input('category',      sql.NVarChar(50),       req.body.category)
      .input('start_time',    sql.DateTime2,          start)
      .input('end_time',      sql.DateTime2,          end)
      .input('duration',      sql.Int,                req.body.duration)
      .input('notes',         sql.NVarChar(sql.MAX),  notes)
      .input('date',          sql.Date,               req.body.date)
      .query(`

        INSERT INTO time_card (company_name, project, category, start_time, end_time, duration, notes, date)
        VALUES(
          @company_name,
          @project,
          @category,
          @start_time,
          @end_time,
          @duration,
          @notes,
          @date
        )
      `).then(function() {
        res.render('index', { body: req.body });
      }).catch(function(err) { next(err); });
    }).catch(function(err) { next(err); });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't understand clearly what is your problem - duplicate query code or twice database calls. But I will try to help you :)

Post data as ajax, return new timecard data on POST succeeded and add it into list on page without reload page.

Another way is store timecards in memory (e.g. `app.locals.timecards`) and update it on each create/update/delete operation with timecards.